# How do I define constant values of UIColor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, constants, uicolor

I want to do something like this, but I cannot get a cooperative syntax.

```
static const UIColor *colorNavbar = [UIColor colorWithRed: 197.0/255.0 green: 169.0/255.0 blue: 140.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
```

I suppose that I could define macros, but they are ugly.

Comment: Yes, Objective-C to be more language specific -- but it is on the iPhone in this case.

Comment: `static UIColor *const color = ....` is possible in Objective-C++. Just change the extension for `*.mm`.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I like to use categories to extend classes with new methods for this sort of thing. Here's an excerpt of code I just wrote today:

```
@implementation UIColor (Extensions)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHueDegrees:(CGFloat)hue saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness {
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:(hue/360) saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1.0];
}

+ (UIColor *)aquaColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithHueDegrees:210 saturation:1.0 brightness:1.0];
}

+ (UIColor *)paleYellowColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithHueDegrees:60 saturation:0.2 brightness:1.0];
}

@end
```

Now in code I can do things like:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = highlight? [UIColor paleYellowColor] : [UIColor whitecolor];
```

and my own defined colors fit right in alongside the system-defined ones.

(Incidentally, I am starting to think more in terms of HSB than RGB as I pay more attention to colors.)

**UPDATE regarding precomputing the value:** My hunch is that it's not worth it. But if you really wanted, you could memoize the values with static variables:

```
+ (UIColor *)paleYellowColor {
    static UIColor *color = nil;
    if (!color) color = [UIColor colorWithHueDegrees:60 saturation:0.2 brightness:1.0];
    return color;
}
```

You could make a macro do do the memoizing, too.

Comment: i like this approach.  it accomplishes the organization I am looking for in the definition an usage.  I was not familiar with (Extensions), I will have to read up on it as it may be appropriate for some other classes I am using.

Finally, (probably getting OT), are there HSB 'picker' utilities like there are RBG pickers.  I like IB, but I find it helpful to see the complementary colors together since, quite often, I want more than one color at a time.

Comment: Oh yeah, but one problem I was trying to resolve, is getting the value precomputed.  I don't want to perform three divisions every time I reference the color.

Comment: Re color picking: I'm not an expert. I use the color picker in Interface Builder. It has a color wheel, sliders for either RGB or HSB, and also a crayon box. I like it.

Comment: Save above code in a UIColor_MyColors.m, then create UIColor_MyColors.h with:

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor ()
+ (UIColor *) aquaColor;
@end`

to use it import UIColor_MyColors.h
`#import "UIColor_QuizColor.h"`

 and refer to the color like this:

`[self.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor  aquaColor]];`

Comment: also if you’re used to using RGB like (255,255,255) you can change use web to transfer RGB to hue value (http://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php) or add this function to the above code

`+ (UIColor *)colorWithWebRed:(CGFloat)red Green:(CGFloat)green Blue:(CGFloat)blue {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255 green:green/255 blue:blue/255 alpha:1.0];
}`

and use it like this
`+ (UIColor *) aquaColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithWebRed:59 Green:89 Blue:152];
}`

Answer (score 35):

I usually make a category of UIColor for each project:

```
@interface UIColor (ProjectName)

+(UIColor *) colorForSomeTable;
+(UIColor *) colorForSomeControl;
+(UIColor *) colorForSomeText;

@end
```

With the constants in the implementation:

```
@implementation UIColor (ProjectName)

+(UIColor *) colorForSomeTable { return [UIColor colorWithRed:...]; }

@end
```

I also do the same for UIFont and UIImage as needed.

Comment: Absolutely great ! My subsidiary question would be, where to put this code ? I have Constants.h/Constants.m files (in my precompiled headers) and I simply want to "declare" a constant color... I don't like putting this kind of code in there... Where would you put it ?

Comment: IMHO this is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

To expand on jasoncrawford's answer (I'd put this in as a comment, but you can't format code in the comments) if you want to precompute the values (or do it only once).

```
+ (UIColor *)paleYellowColor
{
    static UIColor* paleYellow = nil;
    if (paleYellow == nil)
    {
        paleYellow = [UIColor colorWithHueDegrees:60 saturation:0.2 brightness:1.0];
    }
    return paleYellow;
}
```

The reason your original idea doesn't work is because the compiler can only use initialisers outside of functions, not normal code.  You could have achieved something like what you wanted with the initialize methosd e.g.

```
static UIColor* colorNavBar = nil;

+(void) initialize
{
    if (colorNavBar != nil)
    {
        colorNavBar = ....
    }
}
```

NB the `const` qualifier on your original definition is redundant since `UIColor` is immutable anyway.

Comment: Thanks those all all good tips and techniques.  I will likely follow that pattern for some of my other more app specific design tasks.  I am using the class/categories suggested in Jason's first post.  This allows an elegant way to define a theme class of various colors.

Comment: .. oh yeah, as for the const on immutable -- yup, got it!  thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10):

You can 'define' a similar CONSTANT like this:

```
#define FAV_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:24/255.0f green:89/255.0f blue:36/255.0f alpha:0.9]
```

and call it by name like you are used to with constants: `FAV_COLOR`

Hope that helps.

Comment: kasperfn this is the same as the answer from intorpedro (above).  I prefer to avoid macros.  My favored answer is the category answer as it is a better OO use of the language.

Comment: Using macros for constants is a bad thing.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Is there any specific reason? Why macro bad? Is any performance issue? Please brief.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
#define backgroundColorApp [UIColor colorWithRed: 197.0/255.0 green: 169.0/255.0 blue: 140.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0]
```

Comment: I avoid macro solutions when a more type-safe or compiler-safe alternative is available.  You might notice in my original description, I acknowledge that there is a "macro" solution, but they are "ugly."  The ugliness comes in this case since there is a clean solution using the language's category feature.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift, define an extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    
   class func XXXWhiteColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 256, green: 256, blue: 256, alpha: 1.0)
    }
 
    class func XXXGreenColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 73/255.0, green: 212/255.0, blue: 86/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
label.background = UIColor.XXXWhiteColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#define textColorApp [UIColor colorWithRed: 197.0/255.0 green: 169.0/255.0 blue: 140.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0]

myLabel.textColor=textColorApp;
```

Comment: Sorry - still a macro solution.  I prefer the Category solutions and extend the UIColor class.

Answer (score 1):

**Just define below macro in your constant file and pass only RGB value and use anywhere you want**

```
#define RGBCOLOR(r,g,b)[UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]
```

**To use :**

```
[lblCount setTextColor:RGBCOLOR(236, 43, 92)];
```

Comment: Thanks - but I still prefer to avoid macros. My favored answer is the category answer as it is a better OO use of the language.

Comment: I did same but showing expected expression error in objective c

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's also worth mentioning another awesome feature that is rarely talked about: Color Literals. Not only are they easier to read, but they are WAY easier to edit. In Swift,

```
let color: UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 0.3215686275, alpha:
```

When pasted into Xcode, this syntax creates a simple color box. 
[Click here to see an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IttGy.png)

Once you see the box, you can then double click on it to edit it easily. Similarly, you can switch between various IB options, including [RGB Sliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkIxE.png), if you have a specific list of color hex values from your designer.