# How to define non string constants in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constants

I can define global strings like this:

```
// .h
extern NSString * const myString;

// .m
NSString * const myString = @"String";
```

Now I need to define UIcolor similarly, How can I do it?

I'm trying:

```
// .h
extern UIColor * const myColor;

// .m
UIColor * const myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting `error: initializer element is not constant`

Thanks

Comment: Don't know exactly why that happens but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718507/how-do-i-define-constant-values-of-uicolor) question might help you out with a solution.

Comment: Categories (from the linked answer in the accepted answer) is overkill here. Please see this question: Creating a Dictionary Object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855556/creating-a-constant-dictionary-object/

Answer (score 5):

You can't initialize global variables with method calls (or any expression which is not a compile time constant). It works with your `@"String"` example because that is a constant expression. No code needs to be called to evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are a special case, unfortunately. For any other type of object, you will have to initially set it to nil and then provide a value on launch. A good place to do this is in a related class's initialize method (not to be confused with the instance init method), which is guaranteed to be called at least once before the class is instantiated. (Note I said "at least once"; it might be called again depending on the class hierarchy, so check if your globals are nil before you assign them new values.)

Comment: Variables with static storage duration are automatically initialised.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that works is:

```
static UIColor *DefaultColor = nil;

+ (void) initialize {
    static BOOL initiliazed = NO;
    if (initialized)
        return;
    DefaultColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    initialized = YES;
}
```

But of course it’s quite ugly if you just want to initialize a single color.

Comment: You can get rid of that BOOL and just check if DefaultColor is nil.

Comment: or use `dispatch_once()` and don't bother checking anything :)

Comment: Ohó, I didn’t know about `dispatch_once`, thanks.