# Why does using a #define UIColor as CGColorRef cause crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I have a UIColor defined like this:

```
#define kCircleInnerShadowColor [UIColor colorWithWhite:.78 alpha:1.0]
```

Then I use it like this:

```
CGColorRef shadowColorRef = kCircleInnerShadowColor.CGColor;
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(cxt, size, 0, shadowColorRef);
```

However, that causes a BAD_ACCESS crash. If I instead do

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(cxt, size, 0, kCircleInnerShadowColor.CGColor);
```

I don't get a crash, and it works fine. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it crashes, is because of scope issues.
What you are doing is:

1. Create a new UIColor object
2. Retrieve its CGColor pointer
3. Put that pointer into a new variable
4. Release the UIColor object (The next line...)
5. Use the CGColor pointer, which points to bad data already

When you do it in the "one line version", what you do is:

1. Create a new UIColor object
2. Retrieve its CGColor pointer
3. Use the CGColor pointer in a function
4. Release the UIColor object (The next line...)

So because you create the object in the same line where you use it, the compiler automatically keeps the object until the function call returns and proceeds to the next line. Only then it releases the object.

But when you set the CGColor to a variable, what happens is that the compilers sees that the object is not gonna be used anywhere, and sends a release. But the CGColor is not an NSObject and the compiler do not send a "retain" to the CGColor.

If you need the CGColor in a variable, You may want to use **CGColorRetain**.

```
CGColorRef shadowColorRef = CGColorRetain(kCircleInnerShadowColor.CGColor);
```

And then when you are finished with it, **CGColorRelease**

Comment: This is, effectively, an "interior pointer" problem (exactly as Daniel describes).  A potentially better solution if this color is used *a lot* is to have a global variable instead of a #define to avoid lots of memory traffic.

Comment: How can I create a global UIColor variable?

Comment: Which line is releasing the CGColorRef?

Comment: @mohabitar the UIColor releases its own CGColor, so the moment the UIColor is released, the CGColor is released.

Comment: @mohabitar please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718507/how-do-i-define-constant-values-of-uicolor

Comment: So this has nothing to do with the fact that I'm using a #define variable? Would the same problem exist if I did: CGColorRef shadowColorRef = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; and use that ref?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10933/discussion-between-mohabitar-and-daniel-gindi)

Comment: But this is how I've seen it done in professional code: `CGColorRef shadow = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; 
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, size, 0, shadow);` You're saying this is not ok?

Comment: [UIColor blackColor] happens to be something that is reused by the system, because every app and the system itself uses it, and the blackColor message returns the same instance all the time.
But yes, it IS un"professional" to do it this way, because you are counting on something that happens to be the way the system works, but in other cases it might fail you. So you are getting used to bad patterns.